# Grails + MongoDB: what's a replacement for association query criteria?

Tags: grails, mongodb, grails-orm

The MongoDB plugin for Grails (mongodb 1.0-M5) doesn't (yet) support queries of type AssociationQuery.  This means I can't do this:

```
// Find all instances of MyDomainClass whose myHasOneObject.id is in listOfIds
// Throws exception b/c Mongo doesn't support AssociationQuery
MyDomainClass.withCriteria {
    myHasOneObject {
        inList('id', $listOfIds)
    }
    [...]

// FYI, class declaration looks like this:
class MyDomainClass {
    AnotherDomainClass myHasOneObject
    [...]
```

What's an alternative way to do queries like this in MongoDB in Grails?

Thanks!

Comment: that is exactly my question, i am going to issue a question in (http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't support join queries, so you need to do 2 queries or denormalize your data